# Change multi-output loss weights based on epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

Is it possible to change the weights of different outputs of a TF2 model based on the epoch?

Right now I am using the following code snippet to define the priority of the different outputs:

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss=['mean_squared_error', 'mean_squared_error', 'mean_squared_error'],
              loss_weights=[0.25, 1., 1.])
```

However, I would prefer if these weights would change based on the epoch. For example like this:

```
loss_weights=[0.25 + 0.01*epoch, 1. - 0.005*epoch , 1. - 0.005*epoch]
```

Is this possible and if yes. What would be the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.keras.Model` has `_loss_weights_list` property - you could try to change it via custom callback just like `tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler` manipulates with learning rate during training process.

**EDIT:** Another idea is to repeatedly call `model.compile()` and then `model.fit()` for only one epoch:

```
for epoch_idx in range(total_epochs):
    loss_weights=[0.25 + 0.01 * epoch_idx, 1. - 0.005 * epoch_idx, 1. - 0.005 * epoch_idx]
    model.compile(..., loss_weights=loss_weights)
    model.fit(..., epochs=1, initial_epoch=epoch_idx)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems to go in the right direction but I get the following error in my custom callback:

AttributeError: Can't set the attribute "_loss_weights_list", likely because it conflicts with an existing read-only @property of the object. Please choose a different name.

Do you have any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to set it via `tf.keras.backend.set_value`, or change list's elements instead of changing the list itself?

Comment: Thank you very much!
The method from the edited answer worked. But you need to call fit with `epochs=epoch_idx+1` instead of `1` as the parameter. 
The `tf.keras.backend.set_value` method sadly didn't work for me but that might also due to me doing another mistake.

Comment: Glad to help you! Actually, it looks like a nice feature request at TensorFlow's GitHub :)

Comment: "tf.keras.Model has _loss_weights_list property" that doesn't seem to be true (anymore). What comes closest now, I think, is the attribute compiled_loss which has an attribute _user_loss_weights which has the weights. But I couldn't figure out how to set this.